# Table gone after creating relations

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

For the last three days, I have been creating quite some tables in MySQL, using PhpMyAdmin.

For no apparent reason, when creating a relation from one indexed, unsigned field to an indexed, unsigned primary key in another table, I get the error 'MySQL has gone away'.
Then, I refresh the page and my just created table is missing.

Recreating the table is impossible in PhpMyAdmin, since it returns 'Table already exists'. In PhpMyAdmin alternative Adminer, I can recreate this table, but still get the same error when making a relation.

I've checked everything in my knowledge. Datatypes are the same, MySQL doesn't run out of memory, there are not too many connections, it just 'goes away'.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: When attempting to create the foreign key relation, is there any data in either of the tables? If there is, MySQL has to check every record while creating the foreign key.
Also, can you include the SQL to create both tables as well as the foreign key?

Comment: One table already exists, the other one is newly created. The existing one does contain data, but that shouldn't matter, right? Especially since trying again (recreating the table with another name and creating the same relation) sometimes suddenly works.. I'll try reproducing the error and post it here.

Comment: OK, a field with 'unsigned' attribute, no foreign key relations. I changed the 'unsigned' attribute to none and again, table deleted. SQL command:   ALTER TABLE `table_test`
CHANGE `country_id` `country_id` int(10) NOT NULL AFTER `send_method_id`;

Comment: To be clear: There are no errors or warnings in the output, nor in the error log file (if any)? The table just disappears without any sign of where it is going?

Comment: This is in the errog logs:
InnoDB: Failing assertion: UT_LIST_GET_LEN(table->referenced_list) == rbt_size(table->referenced_rbt)
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:41:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;